# add username to order comment history

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-history

I wanna show the username who commented on order history

my question is like below question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219620/add-username-to-order-comment-history

but it is for Magento 1.4 and it doesn't work for me. magento version 1.9.3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a module and override file ( app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php ):

There you will find function **addCommentAction**:

https://github.com/MrRio/magento/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php#L191

and / change line of code from :

```
$order->addStatusToHistory($data['status'], $data['comment'], $notify);
```

To :

```
$current_Admin = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
    if(isset($current_Admin)) {
        $commentwithUser = '[ BY: '.$current_Admin->getUsername().' ] - '.$data['comment'];
    }
$order->addStatusToHistory($data['status'], $commentwithUser, $notify);
```